# Чтение JSON с русским текстом

Tags: java, android, json

Получаю JSON такого плана:

```
{"id":"113","title":"Xin Kai"},{"id":"114","title":"ZX"},{"id":"115","title":"\u00c2\u00c0\u00c7"}
```

где последний title на русском языке.

Достаю из JSONа так:

```
String title = new String(JsonObj.getString("title").getBytes(), "US-ASCII");
```

(пробовал кучу других вариантов).

Отображаю в Андроид приложении.
Английские значения показываются нормально,
а русские в таком виде:
ÂÀÇ, Âåëòà, ÃÀÇ

Как с этим справиться?

Comment: Пробовали вместо `US-ASCII` ставить `UTF-8`?

Answer (score 2):

[Декодер](https://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/decoder/) показал, что используется кодировка WINDOWS-1251, попробуй ее. Ваз, Велта, ГАЗ.